# Home pc as server

Tags: domains, dns

My dns A-record point to my home PC IP that most of the time is down. Does this fact can cause any troubles with my registrar or there is nothing to be worried?

Comment: No problem whatsoever with registrars. They did their job already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just mean the computer is turned off, this will cause problems with Google and other search spiders indexing your site if most of the time they try to crawl your site it's unavailable... but your registrar doesn't care if your domain name is up or down and DNS will still keep forwarding requests to your IP, available or not. The only issue might be if a users browser cached the page not found result and served that during times when the site was up, but a simple browsing history clear will fix that.